# Branch link to open webpage if app not installed. Open app if app installed

Tags: android, ios, branch.io

I currently have branch io integration with my application.

When user presses on branch io link, currently, it will open my app if the user has the app installed. And it will open the app store if user doesn't have the app installed.

Now, after some time, I have implemented a web app that does partial functionality as the app itself. So if the user doesn't have the app installed, i would like them to navigate to my website (with the correct parameters)

How should I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

If you wish to redirect users to your webpage when your App is not installed on the mobile device you should add `$ios_url` and `$android_url` parameters to your links and set the value to your web page URL (make sure to URI encode your web URL).

For Quick links on the Branch dashboard, you can set the iOS/Android redirect to a web URL.

[image]

You can read all the link parameters on your web page by integrating Branch's web SDK. To learn more about the functionality provided by the web SDK and the process of integration, check out the documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/integrate/) and also the Github repo for the SDK [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking#installation).

Comment: Hi @Amruta Is this $ios_redirect or $android_redirect documented somewhere? Can this URL be set dynamically in server when creating such a link? Judging by the screenshot, it is a static url?

Comment: I used an "$ios_url" and "$android_url" it is now directing me to the website all the time. Regardless whether or not the app is installed.

Comment: @user1017674 make sure you are not doing any of the following mentioned [here](https://branchmetrics.github.io/docs/pages/links/integrate/#open-website-instead-of-app), which is causing your links to redirect to the website even when you App is installed.

Comment: Hey @Amruta I indeed set "ios_url" and "android_url" Are you saying that I should not set them to go to app when app installed? And i should only use "ios_redirect" or "android_redirect"? Is this ios_redirect document somewhere? I couldn't seem to find it...

Comment: @user1017674 I am sorry I meant $ios_url and $android_url. There are no parameters, $ios_redirect. Even if you add these parameters they should open your App if installed. The link I shared earlier (here: https://branchmetrics.github.io/docs/pages/links/integrate/#open-website-instead-of-app) mentions all the things that could cause your links to redirect to the website instead of your App. Make sure you are **not** doing any of the following.

Comment: Hi @Amruta. I still don't quite understand. Under both situation, "App installed" and "App not installed" it mentions $ios_url and $android_url.. So am I setting them or not setting them? And what does "Override Universal link / App Link" mean?

Comment: @user1017674 could you please write to `integrations@branch.io`, so that our team could have a look at the links you created and help you solve the issue. Thank you!

Comment: My question is that, I want to create a link and provide a web url inside that for my website, so that when user clicks on the link, it redirects to my web url if the app is not installed. Currently it is always going to "Enter Phone Number" page always if opened on a desktop.